# Trying to understand how to create a payroll query to condense clock ins and outs

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, group-by

I am attempting to teach myself SQL. I am a learn to swim by jumping into the deep end kind of guy, and I think I am drowning. I know far to little currently about forming SQL commands other than basic Select, From, Where, and Group By. I am about to watch some udemy classes to help, but If i have a real world example I can help ground some concepts for me I learn much better.

I have some data in a table for when a person clocks in and out for the day. I am looking to condense the whole day into just one clock in time and one clock out time and the total hours of the day.

SO I dont know much yet about how all the sql parts work together to form a query, and I dont understand the order of execution of these yet. 
So far all I can do is Select the columns from a table and order them by date and time.

For example I have a table like this:

`select Empl_id, AdjClockInDate, AdjClockInTime, AdjClockOutDate, AdjClockOutTime, TotAdjTime
From AttendDet
Where EmplCode = '33'
Order By EmplCode Asc, SearchDate desc, AdjClockInTime Asc`

`empl_id  AdjClockInDate  AdjClockInTime  AdjClockOutDate AdjClockOutTime  TotAdjTime
   33       07/01/2019       07:00            07/01/2019       12:00            5 
   33       07/01/2019       12:00            07/01/2019       12:30           .5
   33       07/01/2019       12:30            07/01/2019       17:50            5`

And what I wanted to get out of it is to group the common dates and empl_id together into a single days over view like this:

`empl_id  AdjClockInDate  AdjClockInTime  AdjClockOutDate AdjClockOutTime  TotAdjTime
   33        07/01/2019        07:00          07/01/2019       17:50           10`

Ignoring the break period of .5 hours and summing up the non break hours.

I think I need to sort these by dates and times first, then get the first entry of clock in columns, and get the last entry for clock out columns. 
This is about as much as I can say as I dont really know what I can use or how to use it for the sql commands.
I am hoping that by getting a solution to this problem I am trying to work on it will greatly help me understand while I go thru the courses so I can make a brain connection to something tangible.
Right now I know this is over my head, but by seeing and breaking it down and understanding the parts will help me tremendously.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want a basic aggregation query:

```
select Empl_id, AdjClockInDate, MIN(AdjClockInTime), AdjClockOutDate, 
       MAX(AdjClockOutTime), SUM(TotAdjTime)
from AttendDet
where Empl_id = '33'
group by Empl_id, AdjClockInDate, AdjClockOutDate;
```

This is a pretty basic query and suggests that you should learn the basics of SQL before diving into the deep end.

Comment: FYI - They may be excluding the LUNCH break.  Your solution is 10.5 while desired results is 10.   OP needs to clarify.

Comment: Thats exactly what I was looking for. My lack of knowledge led me to believe it would be much more complicated. Adding a `and PayCode != '0'` on the where got me exactly when I needed including removing the break (paycode =0).
Simple or not, it helped me understand how these interact more than i had.